# Which shopkeepers dialogs can I safely skip in Shadowrun: Hong Kong?

Tags: shadowrun-hong-kong

I've already played through the main storyline once before now I'm doing it again using a different archetype on hard mode.  However, this time I don't want to wade through all the dialog again for the shopkeepers unless it has to do with the main story (spoilers:)

> Namely, Crafy's dialog.
>  I'm also aware that Maximum Law can offer some me some additional Nuyen for metadata.

Can I safely skip talking to all the other merchants?

Answer (score 1):

You can safely avoid the rest of the shopkeepers in the game if you don't mind missing background story, lore, and side quest dialog. The main story does a pretty good job of guiding you directly where you need to go to progress through it and get all the information for it. So, if you skip the rest of the merchants that aren't related directly to the main story, then you should be fine, if that's your goal.